How can I set up launchctl to run a task that’s missed while my Mac is in sleep?
I have a plist (see below) which executes an app and it Runs At Load and has a startinterval of 14400 (4 hours). I also have the habit of not manually sleeping my mac when at home but rather just blanking the screen (it's connected to power). Querying the log I can see my Mac enters and leave various sleep states during a ~12 hour period (Maintenance Sleep, Idle Sleep, Sleep Service back to Sleep) but during this time my LaunchAgent plist doesn't appear to run the app. My understanding is that launchctl will run the plist it missed during sleep so why isn't this happening?
FYI, the copy2sync.app referenced in plist runs At Load as expected and works fine.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.test.copy2sync</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Applications/copy2sync.app/Contents/MacOS/Automator Application Stub</string>
  </array>
<key>Nice</key>
  <integer>1</integer>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
<key>StartInterval</key>
<integer>14400</integer>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/copytosync1.err</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/copytosync1.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>

How can I change things to run this task while my Mac sleeps?

From the launchd.plist(5) man page:
StartInterval <integer>
 This optional key causes the job to be started every N seconds. If the
 system is asleep during the time of the next scheduled interval firing,
 that interval will be missed due to shortcomings in kqueue(3).  If the
 job is running during an interval firing, that interval firing will
 likewise be missed.

StartCalendarInterval <dictionary of integers or array of dictionaries of
 integers>
 This optional key causes the job to be started every calendar interval as
 specified. Missing arguments are considered to be wildcard. The semantics
 are similar to crontab(5) in how firing dates are specified. Multiple
 dictionaries may be specified in an array to schedule multiple calendar
 intervals.

 Unlike cron which skips job invocations when the computer is asleep,
 launchd will start the job the next time the computer wakes up.  If
 multiple intervals transpire before the computer is woken, those events
 will be coalesced into one event upon wake from sleep.

Example, to run a job every 4 hours starting at midnight daily:
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>4</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>12</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>16</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>20</integer>
    </dict>
</array>

There may be a bug in launchd that will cause the job to run at an offset to the times specified, depending on the time zone, but that shouldn't matter for your purposes.

So the answer is to use StartCalendarInterval and not StartInterval. Is RunAtLoad still allowed?

This optional key is used to control whether your job is launched once at the time the job is loaded. The default is false. This key should be avoided, as speculative job launches have an adverse effect on system-boot and user-login scenarios.

OK, so it's StartCalendarInterval that will run any missed 'firings'. In that case, how would I run a job every 4 hours? Would I need to specify multiple start times in a plist?

See edited answer.

Great! thanks, I'll do that.
